# How can I send E-mail with a ssl type connection cryptography

Tags: c#, email, ssl

I'm trying to send an e-mail with MailMessage and smtpclient class with enablessl = true, but I receive timeout on every connection.
setting it in outlook, there is an option "use de following type of connection cryptography", which have the following options: none, ssl, tls or automatic.
choosing the option ssl I can send e-mail throught the outlook.
How can I do it in C#?

Comment: You probably have the wrong port.

Comment: You do it in C# exactly as you described.  There is not enough information to know why the connection is timing out.  Some ISPs use a non-standard port for SSL connections.

Comment: I'm using the port 465 as the provider informed.

Comment: In C# I just have the property EnableSsl in the smtpclient, I put it true, but I think it's not enough.

Comment: Eric J., do you know how to use the option "use de following type of connection cryptography" in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set Port property to match the protocol used.

You can probably get along with `STARTTLS` on port `25`, while for `SMTPS` (encrypted connection from start, that is, "SSL") you need port `465`.

EDIT:

As it turns out, `SmtpClient` *does not support* this method of SSL.

From the documentation:

> An alternate connection method is where an SSL session is established
>   up front before any protocol commands are sent. This connection method
>   is sometimes called SMTP/SSL, SMTP over SSL, or SMTPS and by default
>   uses port 465. This alternate connection method using SSL is not
>   currently supported.

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So that you **SHOULD** use STARTTLS, which involves switching back to port `25`.
You might also try port `587`.

Comment: sorry, I'm not set it wrong, I set port = 465 as you mentioned.